# JSON returning when making requests in a for loop

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I'm making GET requests in my array for loop (`loadSupporter(completion: @escaping(()->())`). It gets the right data for each loop except for the last 3-6 loops.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
 
class NotificationVC: Toolbar, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var notifications:[NotificationViewModel] = [] {
        didSet {
            loadSupporter(completion: {
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }   
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        loadNotifications()
    }
    
    func loadNotifications() {
           print("loadNotifications")
           if let user_id = profile?.sub {
               let getNotifications = GETNotificationsByUserID(user_id: user_id)
               getNotifications.getNotifications { notifications in
                self.notifications = notifications.map { notification in
                let ret = NotificationViewModel()
                ret.mainNotification = notification
    
                return ret
             }
           }
        }
      }
    
    func loadSupporter(completion: @escaping(()->())) {
        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
        var index:Int = 0
        for notification in self.notifications {
            myGroup.enter()
            if let supporter_id = notification.mainNotification?.supporter_id {
            GetUsersById2(id: supporter_id).getUser { user in
                self.notifications[index].supporter_info = user
                index += 1
            
                myGroup.leave()
            }
                
        }
      }
        myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
          completion()
       }
    }
 
 
//Web Service
import Foundation
 
class GetUsersById2 {
 
    var id:String
    var dataTask:URLSessionDataTask?
    
    init(id:String) {
        self.id = id
    }
    
    
    func getUser(completion: @escaping (UsersModel) -> ()) {
        
        
        var components = URLComponents()
           components.scheme = "https"
           components.host = "dev-owihjaep.auth0.com"
           components.path = "/api/v2/users/\(id)"
 
 
        let url = components.url
      
         guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
         var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
         request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let accessToken = AccessToken().accessToken
        request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
 
        dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error Getusersbyid2 \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            guard let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UsersModel.self, from: data) else {
                print("Unable to decode responseData")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(user)
                print("GetUsersById2 user \(user)")
            }
            
        }
        dataTask?.resume()
        
    }
}
```

I know it's not the `supporter_id` passed into the url because they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't manage the index variable yourself, use the `enumerated()` API.

And run the `enter` line after the `if let` check

<strike>`var index:Int = 0`</strike>

```
for (index, notification) in self.notifications.enumerated() {
    if let supporter_id = notification.mainNotification?.supporter_id {
        myGroup.enter()
        GetUsersById2(id: supporter_id).getUser { user in
           self.notifications[index].supporter_info = user
           myGroup.leave()
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Although I'm still getting nil for some loops. Kinda confusing.

Comment: You have to call `completion` in any case in `getUser` (for example with the `Result` type) otherwise the group counter gets confused.

Comment: I've never used Result in my GET request before so I don't know exactly what you mean. Can you try to write out the code in your answer?

Comment: Otherwise declare the closure type as `(UsersModel?) -> ()` and replace all occurrences of `return` with `completion(nil); return`.  In the completion handler check if `UsersModel` is not `nil` but call **always** `leave`.

Comment: "In the completion handler check if UsersModel is not nil but call always leave". What do you mean by this?

Comment: `if let user = user { self.notifications[index].supporter_info = user }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219631/discussion-between-ddavis25-and-vadian).